# Configuring Wildfly transaction log

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, transactions, wildfly-8, jta

I'm trying to configure Wildlfy 8.2.1 to show transaction log and transaction metrics. I have an application which uses JTA database connection and I want to see failed/rollback transactions. So far I tried to enable statistics for transactions in both transaction manager and in persistence.xml, and still both transaction recovery logs and transaction metrics shows empty. I understand that transaction log will only show failed transactions as per *Transaction recovery log* description:

> The persistent information that the transaction manager stores for the
>   purpose of recovering a transaction in the event of failure. The probe
>   operation will add and remove transactions from the model as the
>   corresponding real transactions start and finish the prepare and
>   commit phases. A stuck transaction will remain in the model until
>   either it is completed or explicitly removed by the delete operation

So I tried to create scenarios where the transaction will rollback, but it still not shown in the log.

**My datasource configuration:**

[image: My datasource configuration]

**Transaction manager configuration:**

[image: Transaction manager configuration]

**Empty metrics:**
[image: Transaction metrics]

What I'm missing, how to make Wildfly show something?